# PHP mkdir not working with folder that has 'System Action' or 'Device' reference name

Tags: php, windows, ftp, mkdir

We have a web base application that generates folder in a FTP location and folder names are based on the data provided inside the XML. 
Folder names has unlimited possibility and recently we encountered this data that requires **CON** as a folder name.

Now since **CON** is one of the names that you can't use, and yes the corporate is using Windows Machine, is there anyway to **force** create this folder?

The current code uses `mkdir` to generate folder, but it looks like it's not going anywhere.

This folder will be access by different users from time to time using FTP connections bridge by the app, so is there any possible negative/limitation that we can expect in terms of file manipulation inside the folder created?

Other solution I think is:
Filter items that has **CON** and rename it to something else, but that is the last resort and that would cost high modification inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
mkdir("\\\\.\\C:\\path\\to\\con");
```

Based on [Unable to rename a folder or a file as 'con'](https://superuser.com/q/86999/213663#129260).

Comment: I'm getting `mkdir(): No such file or directory` through php and ftp path. I tried also in command line locally, but I'm getting `The directory or file cannot be created.`. Perhaps it doesn't work anymore with Windows 8 and Windows 10 OS?

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 (only). Works ok. What exact command do you try? Show us. What version of PHP?

Comment: version 5.6.14, sorry my bad, it work on command line. But through ftp it seems I can't make it work. `$folder = '//./'.FILE_SERVER_FTTP_CREDENTIAL.FILE_SERVER_PATH.$folder_name.'/'.$folder_name.'_'.$folder_id.'/';` where that returns `//./ftp://username:password@Constant/Path/CON/CON_1234` and I used it as `mkdir($folder);` and giving me the error: `mkdir(): No such file or directory`. I should be using forward slash since this is a URI right?

Comment: it looks like I'll be having an **issue** (bwDraco's answer  in your link) during file manipulation inside this folder through php. e.g. copying,deleting,renaming. Maybe I should throw the towel and just go for renaming files with reserved words?

Comment: OK, so if your question is really about FTP, you should show your code in the question to make clear, what you are doing. You should also specify what FTP server are you using, as the problem and its solution is likely very server-specific. Also you should tell us if you are able to create such folder anyhow, using any (even GUI) FTP client.